# Format for query condition

Tags: mysql

The code below is part of a query.  I seem to have the format wrong for the part of the code that says `AND ON C2.loginid = S2.loginid`.  What format should I use?

Thanks in advance,

John

```
LEFT JOIN (
    SELECT S2.loginid, COUNT(1) AS total 
    FROM submission S2
    INNER JOIN comment C2
    ON C2.submissionid = S2.submissionid
    AND ON C2.loginid = S2.loginid
    GROUP BY S2.loginid
) scs ON scs.loginid = l.loginid
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`AND ON C2.loginid = S2.loginid` ==> Remove `ON` after the `AND`

```
LEFT JOIN (
    SELECT S2.loginid, COUNT(1) AS total 
    FROM submission S2
    INNER JOIN comment C2
    ON C2.submissionid = S2.submissionid
      AND C2.loginid = S2.loginid
    GROUP BY S2.loginid
) scs ON scs.loginid = l.loginid
```